# como mostrar imagenes que tengo en una base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

que tal amigos pido su ayuda , tengo una tabla en mi base de datos donde guardo las imagenes y quiero mostrarlas en mi pagina html , pero que estas  al momento de mostrarlas se vayan acomodando horizontalmente en hilera , en lugar de mostrarlas hacia abajo

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT n.id_not,n.titulo_not, n.desc_not, p.*  FROM noticias as n INNER JOIN foto as p ON n.id_not=p.id_not WHERE n.id_not='$id'")
                                                    or die('Hubo un error en la consulta : '.mysqli_error($mysqli));

                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                    if($row['titulo_not']!=$noticia){ 

                    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <br>
                        <h1 style="font-size: 25px; color:#19396A; font-family: soberana;"><?php echo $row['titulo_not']; ?></h1>
                        <div class="thumbnail">


                        <p style="font-size: 25px; color:#19396A; font-family: soberana;"><?php echo $row['desc_not']; ?></p>


                        <?php

                        $noticia=$row['titulo_not'];

                         } ?>

                          <div class=".col-md-8 " style="display: inline-block; ">

                            <a href="<?php echo $row['ubicacion']; ?>" target="_blank"> <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image" src="<?php echo $row['ubicacion']; ?>" style="  margin:10px; width: 300px; height:230px;" title="<?php echo $row['titulo_not']; ?>"/></a>


                        </div>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <?php 

                      }

                     ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Muestra el código que llevas para poder ayudarte a adecuarlo

Comment: listo esto es lo que llevo

Comment: Creo que tu problema es con el CSS, no con la consulta a la base. Si entiendo bien lo que necesitas es modificar los estilos que utilizas en tu while.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvendio Jeovani, Me parece que estás utilizando bootstrap, intenta cambiando las clases de tu etiqueta `div` padre
Cómo la tienes es así

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
```

Cómo debería ser es así

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
```

De esta forma en dispositivos a partir de tablets en adelante se verán tres imágenes por fila si cambias a `col-md-3` se verán 4 por fila.

Te recomiendo que lo hagas así pues `col-sm-12` hace que sólo se vea una imagen por fila en dispositivos embebidos, es más cómodo a la vista.

Comment: gracias pero no funciono , seguire intentando